# navbar toggler icon does not appear angular2

Tags: html, angular, toggle, navbar, expand

i got a problem i have my toggler bar

[Image of toggler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkNZ2.png)

when i put something in the spann it doesn't toggle.
it appears like this

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DicO3.png)

so this is my code, what i am doing wrong?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-company-red">

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" >
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </span>

                </button>

                <div id="navbar-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse float-xs-none">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <img src="assets/logo.png" hspace="20" style="width:50px;height:50px; ">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">
                                <span translate>Home</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" routerLink="/gallery" routerLinkActive="active">
                                <span translate>order</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link text-uppercase" routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive="active">
                                <span translate>order</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "when i put something in the span it doesn't toggle."?

Comment: It looks like it's because that span is literally the button, so by putting things in the span, you're simply adding the text to the button. You can tell because within the span, there are more spans, and each one is a line for the button. You'll probably have to create another div that reveals itself once you click the button!

Comment: @BasavarajBhusani like in the second image i put, i add   " aaaaa, bbb,cccc"   in the span

Comment: @nonexistent i try in that way, but still the same :/

Comment: Can you add the code for what you tried to do? And can you also explain what exactly you're trying to accomplish? Are you trying to make it so that you can toggle the viewing of the menu?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little bit confused, can you explain why you need to add something into the span to toggle? Are you trying to toggle the navbar-menu?